# After "submit" JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

Is it possible in Yii2, when you click "submit" and have to wait until it is loaded, to have a window, or at least a message that "it's loading so be patient"? I have little experience with JavaScript, but I suppose that's the way to do that.
I tried that:

```
<style>
#loading {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  background-color: green;
  line-height: 5;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
</style>

<script>
$('#formularz').on("submit", function() {
  $("#loading").show();
});
</script>

<h1>Dodaj numery do przedzwonienia</h1>
<h3>Wybierz zamówienie, którego numery chcesz przedzwonić:</h3>

<div class="order-form" id="formularz">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Order::find()->all(), 'id', 'id')) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton("Przedzwoń", ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>

<div id="loading">
    Ładowanie trwa...
</div>
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need to use JSExpression, also add console.log to see if it triggers
if you hit F12 on your browser and check console... hope it helps

```
<?php
    // this goes on top of file to other uses right after namespace
    use yii\web\JsExpression;
?>

<style>
#loading {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  background-color: green;
  line-height: 5;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
</style>

<?php
    // you might want to use JSExpression and check if it triggers
    $this->registerJs("
        $('#formularz').on('submit', function() {
            $('#loading').show();
            console.log('loading...');
        });
"); ?>

<h1>Dodaj numery do przedzwonienia</h1>
<h3>Wybierz zamówienie, którego numery chcesz przedzwonić:</h3>

<!-- you can not use same id twice -->
<div class="order-form" id="formularz-div">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'formularz',
]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Order::find()->all(), 'id', 'id')) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton("Przedzwoń", ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>

<div id="loading">
    Ładowanie trwa...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` element has no `submit` event. Submit event is for a `<form>`. So, your form opening tag should be:

```
<form id="formularz" .....>
```

Or you can modify jquery selector like this:

```
$('#formularz form').on("submit", function() {
  $("#loading").show();
});
```

This means that on submitting some `<form>` inside `div#formularz` your event will happen.

I'm not familiar with Yii, but try something like:

```
ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'formularz',
]);
```

And then check generated html.

Comment: Okay, but I'm using Yii, where I start form like that: `$form = ActiveForm::begin();`, so where can I put it? I can't start one form twice.

Comment: I tried, no result. I also tried to find id of form generated by Yii, but it didn't change a bit.